# Querying highest value by keys from database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

With the following table:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  Parent_ID  |  Item_ID  |  Count  |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      1      |     1     |    1    |
|      1      |     1     |    5    |
|      1      |     1     |    4    |
|      1      |     2     |    7    |
|      1      |     2     |    2    |
|      2      |     1     |    2    |
|      2      |     1     |    3    |
|      2      |     2     |    2    |
|      2      |     2     |    4    |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

I would like to get the highest available count for given `Parent_ID` and `Item_ID`, like the following:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  Parent_ID  |  Item_ID  |  Count  |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      1      |     1     |    5    |
|      1      |     2     |    7    |
|      2      |     1     |    3    |
|      2      |     2     |    4    |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

**How would I go about doing this using LINQ/SQL in C#?** For example, I would like the highest item counts for parent id 1.  This would be something like:

```
int parentId = 1;
var counts = from c in database.Items where parentId == c.parentId 
//this gets all counts from items for parent id 1, but I am just looking
//for the highest count per item for parent id 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group by multiple fields, you can group using an anonymous object:

```
var counts = from item in database.Items
             group item by new { item.ParentId, item.ItemId } into itemGroup
             select new Item()
                    {
                        ParentId = itemGroup.Key.ParentId,
                        ItemId = itemGroup.Key.ItemId,
                        Count = itemGroup.Max(x => x.Count)
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Parent_ID, Item_ID, MAX(Count)
FROM ...
GROUP BY Parent_Id, Item_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select parent_id, 
       item_id, 
       max(count) as count
from your_table
group by parent_id, item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ2SQL I think you want something like:

```
var counts = database.Items.GroupBy(p => p.parentId).Max(p => p.Key);
```

Comment: He wants to group on the pair of parentID and childID (not just parentID), although that's not a significant change from this code.